# Is it possible to create a virtual pageview from an event using a custom filter?

Tags: google-analytics

I've released a mobile app (Android) which I track using Google Analytics. As my experience with Google Analytics is little, I did some mistakes by not knowing when to use events versus virtual pageviews.

My app has a login and a signup screen and I'd like to track the conversion rate of users signing up for an account. The app tracks the page views (`/Account/Login` and `/Account/Create Account`) and the actual login and account creation as individual events (Category: `Account`, Action:`Logged In` and `Account Created`).

*So here's my problem*: In order to do a nice funnel analysis, I should have created virtual pageviews instead of events if the user logs in or creates an account. Though I can create a goal based on events it will not tell me the drop off rates in the individual steps the user takes. Only the funnel visualization can do this AFAIK.

Is there a way to automatically create page views using custom filters in Google Analytics? I've tried to setup a filter like this:

```
Field A -> Extract A      Event Category   Account
Field B -> Extract B      Event Action     (Account Created|Logged In)
Output To -> Constructor  Request URI      /Account/$B1
Field A Required          Yes
Field B Required          Yes
Override Output Field     Yes
Case Sensitive            No
```

However, that doesn't seem to work. I do not see any additional page views or any other changes. Any suggestions?

*(Of course I could release an update to the app and I will probably also do this soon, but the above solution would help me with my experiments right now - without having to alter the source code every time I have "a new idea" how to improve the analytics data)*

Comment: I've continued researching on this topic and tried various options I could think of. Looks like this might just not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I've found that it's impossible to achieve this without updating the mobile clients. However, moving forward I will take a closer look at [Google Tag Manager](http://www.google.com/tagmanager/) which allows much greater flexibility.